# Developed a program using C... What should I use to make it into a web application?

Tags: web-apps, c

I'm a sophomore (taking Freshman level courses due to changing major) Computer Science major currently. I've only taken one Intro level programming class so far using C, and I'm teaching myself Python right now. I'm learning Java next semester. Over the winter break, I developed a program that calculates your GPA based on my university's specific point system.

I'm pretty new to creating web applications and I've tried to do some research on how to go about using my C program to create a web application, but honestly I've found nothing helpful. Can anyone suggest software that would allow me to do this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: C is very rarely used to develop web pages, you'll find that Python suits that role much better. Java is also widely used. I would look into using those two first. And regardless, tons of JavaScript.

Comment: This site is not about giving advice for developing software. Try a discussion site such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/. By the way, http://www.Vaadin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard, Jennifer.

As others mentioned above, your question is way off-topic here (click the question mark above right to find out what you should ask (hint: ask us to recommend software – apps, libraries, that sort of thing)).

Since it’s off-topic, I will be naughty & answer it quickly before it is put on hold or closed :-)   We are here to help after all.

You can do this using [Web assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly).

See [this page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=wasm) for browser support, which is fairly solid, except for Internet Explorer (which currently has only [2.82% market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share) and falling, so can be considered an edge case and discounted).

Read [WebAssembly: How and why](https://blog.logrocket.com/webassembly-how-and-why-559b7f96cd71)



> How to run native code in the browser, why would you do that, and
>   what does it all mean for JavaScript and the future of web development

Take a look at [Get started with WebAssembly — using only 14 lines of JavaScript](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-b37b6aaca1e4)

and DuckDuckGo further.

Welcome aboard, and good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should research what the CGI interface does. CGI means [Common Gateway Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) here.

On your webserver, you could put your C program into a directory that has special permissions for the web server process. For instance, the directory must be enterable by the web server, and your C program must have execute permission for the "Others" group.

CGI  specifies how your webserver takes input data from the web user. Your webserver then calls your C program as a console script, collects the output from the C binary, and then sends that output back to the user.

CGI was used a lot in the 1990s, but it does not scale up to 100s of users, has difficulty with long-running processes and has security problems. Therefore it has fallen out of fashion in the 2000s.

But for, say, an inhouse application with a small set of users, CGI programs can still be used, and IMHO programming CGI scripts is a useful skill to have.

Comment: Hmmm, you just made me realize that I assumed he program was going to run in the browser, whereas you are correct in that it can also run on the server. Personally, I think she ought to lean JS and either Node.JS or PHP, but ... given the constraints of the question ...